# Reorder SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Due to lack of funds (till subscriptions can be taken again) we cannot pay for a developer to correct the way results are displayed in some query/searches.

What happens in these cases is that the order in which the rows are stored in displayed for the user.

Requirement *As an interim - carry out the AlphaNumeric reorder the table of results so that the positions of each even is in Aplhanumerical order 1 to 10 then 11 and larger numbers below followed by alphabetical letters.*

This is an example of how it can appear

```
Pos Name    Event 
-------------------
7   Grey    Javelin 
8   Hill    Javelin 
9   Jones   Javelin    
C   Norris  Javelin 
1   Adams   Javelin 
10  Kirk    Javelin 
11  Lewis   Javelin    
12  Moore   Javelin 
2   Bevan   Javelin 
3   Cain    Javelin 
4   Douglas Javelin    
5   Evans   Javelin 
6   Fell    Javelin 
C   Owens   Javelin 
D   Pick    Javelin    
F   Quill   Javelin
```

The correct order should be as follows

```
Pos Name    Event
-------------------
1   Adams   Javelin
2   Bevan   Javelin
3   Cain    Javelin
4   Douglas Javelin
5   Evans   Javelin
6   Fell    Javelin
7   Grey    Javelin
8   Hill    Javelin
9   Jones   Javelin
10  Kirk    Javelin
11  Lewis   Javelin
12  Moore   Javelin
C   Norris  Javelin
C   Owens   Javelin
D   Pick    Javelin
F   Quill   Javelin
```

While it is not ideal I was wondering if someone has a simple way to reorder. I would be okay in this being placed into another table as part of the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pos column seems to be alphnumeric so numbers will not sort by value.

Try below

```
SELECT Pos,Name,Event
FROM (
SELECT Pos,Name,Event,CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Pos) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END tag
FROM tableName
) tmp
ORDER BY tag,CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Pos) = 1 THEN CAST(Pos AS INT) ELSE -1 END,Pos
```

`tag` column will bring numeric values to beginning and push alphabetical values to back. Then inside statement `CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Pos) = 1 THEN CAST(Pos AS INT) ELSE -1 END` we are casting numeric values to int so that they are sorted by values and leave the alphabetical values to be sorted by charcter values as it is.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is notoriously bad at recognizing numbers - unfortunately. I would much rather use `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT` and try to convert the string to a number - and if it fails and returns `NULL`, you know it's an alphanumeric (string) value - not a number - just that much more reliable!

Comment: Worked reorder using those query details Mudassir Hassan. Thank you with a bit of work I will be able to replace the table with a freshly sorted one, with a rename or two.

Answer (score 4):

This is a situation where you want to use `try_convert()`/`try_cast()`:

```
order by (case when try_convert(int, pos) is not null then 1 else 2 end),
         try_convert(int, pos),
         pos
```

The first puts numbers first.  The second orders by the number.  The third orders everything else.

I strongly advise you not to use `isnumeric()`.  It has fun anomalies, such as the fact the `'-'` and `'.'` return "true".

Answer (score 0):

You can use next query:

```
select * 
from Tbl 
order by 
    ISNUMERIC(Pos) DESC, -- set numerical values first
    TRY_CAST(Pos AS INT); -- order by numeric value
```

[MS SQL fidle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=7337cb836ff6f5b64e6d10787fffce32&php_version=null&sql_version=mssql2017)